# Is this a case of conditional probability or not?

Tags: probability

sorry in advance if this is very basic

I have been asked a question of the following form:

The chance of catching a cold in 1 meeting with someone else with a cold is 1/10

Assume A has a cold

If B meets A and later meets C, what is the probability of C catching a cold

I feel like this is just a case of multiplying the probability of catching a cold by itself e.g.

1/10 * 1/10 == 1/100

However, my very non-mathsy brain is confused by the idea of conditional probability, as to me it seems like C catching a cold is conditional on B catching a cold which would alter the calculation.

Once again apologies if this is very obvious!

Comment: Well, you have to assume that $A$ has the only cold to start (it changes things if $B$ or $C$ could catch a cold from some other source).  And you must assume that these two meetings are the only meetings between the three. But under those assumptions your calculation is right.

Comment: Many probability problems that can be solved without conditional probability can alternatively be worked out in terms of non-trivial conditional probabilities. An answer has already been posted showing a correct way to do this for your problem. Notice that it does _not_ change the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the tree diagram:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

where $B$ - catch cold, $B'$ - do not catch cold.

The required probability is:
$$\begin{align}P(C)=&P(C\cap B)+P(C\cap B')=\\
=&P(B)\cdot P(C|B)+P(B')\cdot P(C|B')=\\
=&\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}+\frac{9}{10}\cdot 0=\\
=&\frac{1}{100}.\end{align}$$
Note: The only source of catching cold is $A$ for $B$ and $B$ for $C$, and the probability both times is $1/10$.